# How to Unpivot a Struct in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, unpivot

I have a table with an ID and then a struct. I want to turn each element of the struct into a new row with the struct field name being a value in the column `Period` and the value being the structures value. See table below

Query that generated the table:

[image: Click to see query that generated the table]

Current data

[image: Click to see table structure]

I tried this:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM `business-analytics-workbench.RAW.User_Activity` as UA
    UNPIVOT(Activity FOR PERIOD in (Last_7_Days,Last_14_Days,Last_30_Days,Last_90_Days,First_Date_AEST,Last_Date_AEST))
```

But I get this error "Unrecognized name: Last_7_Days at [3:33]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot unpivot columns with different data types (in your example those are INT64 and DATE). So consider below approach

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Document_ID, User_Activity.* 
  FROM `business-analytics-workbench.RAW.User_Activity` as UA
)
UNPIVOT(Activity FOR PERIOD in (Last_7_Days,Last_14_Days,Last_30_Days,Last_90_Days))
```

If applied to sample data in y our question  output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since these are part of a struct, try using the full struct field name

```sql
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `business-analytics-workbench.RAW.User_Activity` as UA
UNPIVOT(
    Activity 
    FOR PERIOD in (
        User_Activity.Last_7_Days,
        User_Activity.Last_14_Days,
        User_Activity.Last_30_Days,
        User_Activity.Last_90_Days
    )
)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to pivot table without using PIVOT operator  - in this case you have less restriction - consider below example

```
select Document_ID, split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] PERIOD, split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] Activit
from (
  select Document_ID, User_Activity.* 
  from `business-analytics-workbench.RAW.User_Activity`
) t,
unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv
where split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] != 'Document_ID'
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]